# Python Selenium: Find row by partial text then click checkbox that has no identifier to that partial text

Tags: python, selenium

I need to click a checkbox on a table by serial number but the serial number isn't tied into the checkbox by any unique identifier:

[image]

Here's the serial:

```
 <a href="#" style="padding-left:10px;" id="inactive_406906" onclick="getDeviceInfo(406906); return false;"> SZK190052 </a>
```

Here's the checkbox:

```
 <input id="inactiveDeviceSelectionCheckbox" class="deviceSelectionCheckBox" name="inactiveList" type="checkbox" value="406906" onclick="onClickDeviceCheckbox(this, document.myform.deviceInactiveCheckAll, 406906, false, false, false, false, false, 0)" onchange="populateInactiveCheckedDevice(this, 406906, false, false)">
```

Here's my attempt:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//a[text()='SSJD90134']]//input[@class='deviceSelectionCheckBox']").click()
```

I get the following error:

```
 Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tr[.//a[text()='SSJD90134']]//input[@class='deviceSelectionCheckBox']"}
```

Unfortunately its not working, any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the error? can you share a link to that page or entire HTML of it?

Comment: i added the error to the original post. Its a private site behind a login so i can't share the page but goto https://obsessedwithexcellence.com/stackoverflow/example.html and right click view page source for the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. There is space between your text you are searching.
Use below xpath.

```
//tr[.//a[normalize-space(text())='SSJD90134']]//input[@class='deviceSelectionCheckBox']
```

so your code be like

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//a[normalize-space(text())='SSJD90134']]//input[@class='deviceSelectionCheckBox']
").click()
```

---

One more Xpath option:

```
//td[.//a[normalize-space(text())='SSJD90134']]/preceding-sibling::td//input[@class='deviceSelectionCheckBox']
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `text()='SSJD90134'` you can use `contains(.,'SSJD90134')` so that instead of

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//a[text()='SSJD90134']]//input[@class='deviceSelectionCheckBox']").click()
```

You can use

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//a[contains(.,'SSJD90134')]]//input[@class='deviceSelectionCheckBox']").click()
```

Or, as mentioned by Kunduk you can remove spaces with `normalize-space()` method

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//a[normalize-space() = 'SSJD90134']]//input[@class='deviceSelectionCheckBox']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces around the link test:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[matches(text(),'SZK190052']//input").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()=' SZK190052 ']//input").click()
```